# Negative Area of a Triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

If $A, B, C$ are the $3$ coordinates of the vertices of $\bigtriangleup ABC$, then the area of the triangle is $\frac{1}{2} |\delta_{ABC}|$ where, $$\delta_{ABC}=(x_1-x_2)(y_2-y_3)-(y_1-y_2)(x_2-x_3)$$ We can also write the area without the **modulus** or the **absolute value** of $\delta_{ABC}$ but this may result the area to be ***negative*** because $\delta_{ABC}$ could be negative depending on the clockwise/anticlockwise loop I'm creating when choosing the order of the vertices.

We can also write our well known `area of a triangle formula` to be equal to the former formula as *(without the modulus)*: $$\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ABC} = \frac{1}{2} AB \times CN $$ only if we consider $N$ to be the coordinate of the foot of the altitude from vertex $C$ to the opposite side $AB$. [Visualize it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xyimj8aeez).

### Context:

Look at this [diagram](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lqcs4ks6c1). If $CN$ and $DM$ both are perpendicular to the line $AB$, then $\bigtriangleup CNE$ $\bigtriangleup DME$ is simillar.
Now, consider by $SSS$ similarity $$\frac{CN}{DM}=\frac{CE}{DE}=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$$
$$\therefore \frac{\bigtriangleup ABC}{\bigtriangleup ABD}\bbox[yellow,5px]{= \frac{\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ABC}}{\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ABD}} = \frac{\frac{1}{2} AB \times CN}{\frac{1}{2} AB \times DM}}=\frac{m_1}{m_2}$$

$\implies \frac{m_1}{m_2}=\frac{ \delta_{ABC}}{\delta_{ABD}}$ the ratio positive $(+)$ and negative $(-)$ implies $AB$ divides $CD$ line segment at the point $E$ externally and internally respectively. Now let's back to my original question which hopefully doesn't require the context.

### $\pmb{My~ Question:}$

The question that is troubling me is, if you look at my sample [diagram](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xyimj8aeez), $AB$  and $CN$ both looks positive to me as they are distance between points and I have this written $\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ABC} = \frac{1}{2} AB \times CN $ when deriving the formula above in coordinate geometry in my textbook but I can't understand if I write $\frac{1}{2} AB \times CN$ instead of $\frac{1}{2} \delta_{ABC}$ `(where we might get negative value)` then where does scope of being negative comes in as $AB$ and $CN$ both should be positive?

Comment: With the $\frac12(\text{base})(\text{height})$ formula, you essentially have to assign a sign "manually", according to the same vertex-loop direction criterion as before. You can think of this as assigning signs to the lengths themselves. Taking the direction $A\to B$ as "positive" (and "forward"), the direction $N\to C$ is "positive" if it points "to the left" (making a counter-clockwise turn from "forward") and "negative" if it points "to the right" (a clockwise turn). Then, the product of these *signed* lengths will itself be positive or negative in accordance with the coordinate formula.

Comment: @Blue, in that case would $AB$ mean $A \rightarrow B$ and $BA$ mean $B \rightarrow A$?

Comment: That's the idea, yes. I should perhaps clarify that the base-times-height formula using segment names is best written as $\frac12|\overline{AB}||\overline{NC}|$ where $|\overline{XY}|$ represents the *signed* distance from $X$ to $Y$. It's important that "height" be thought of as directed *from* the base *to* the opposite vertex. (This can be formalized using vectors, which I'm avoiding here. But a warning: Writing "$\times$" for simple multiplication can/will be confused w/the notation for the "vector cross product". What's extra-confusing is that the cross product helps find signed areas.)